# Breaking out of Promise chain

Tags: javascript, promise

I am creating a function that returns a Promise to be used in `Promise.all(myArray.map(saidFunction))` with Bluebird. In this function I will check whether a record exists in DB and return if it does, and continue doing other stuff otherwise.

```
function saidFunction((objectInfo)) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    app.models.MyObjectType.exists(objectInfo['id'])
    .then((exists) => {
      if (exists) return resolve('Object already exists');
    })
    .then(() => {
      console.log('If object does not exist, print this and do some other stuff');
    })
    .then(() => {
      return resolve('Successfully completed');
    })
    .catch((error) => return reject(error));
  });
}
```

My problem is that even if the object exists, it prints `If object does not exist, print this`. So I'm looking for a solution to return the Promise without continuing to next then functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case a few `then` callbacks include only synchronous code, you should join them and validate `exists` in a single callback.

Also, avoid promise constructor antipattern, `app.models.MyObjectType.exists` already returns a promise, so you shouldn't create a new one.

```
function saidFunction((objectInfo)) {
  return app.models.MyObjectType
    .exists(objectInfo['id'])
    .then(exists => {
      if (exists) {
        console.log('Object already exists');
        return true;
      }
      console.log('If object does not exist, print this and do some other stuff');
      return false;
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
  });
}
```

**Update:**

In the case when you need to do asynchronous tasks, using the results of the previous async calls, you can use `Promise.all`:

```
function saidFunction((objectInfo)) {
  return app.models.MyObjectType
    .exists(objectInfo['id'])
    .then(objExists => {
      if (objExists) {
        return [true, true];
      }
      return Promise.all([false, ensureFolderExistsAsync()]);
    })
    .then(([objExists, folderExists]) => {
      if (!objExists && folderExists) {
        return saveIconAsync();
      }
      return null;
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
  });
}
```

In the example above I return an array `[true, true]`, when the object exists (and folder exists too). If the object doesn't exist, I check that folder exists calling `ensureFolderExistsAsync` and using `Promise.all` to pass the `objectExists` value and the result of async call.

Comment: Thanks. I will write 3-4 more promises though. Since I will be doing other stuff inside then, wouldn't that look like one of those old callback chains if Async is not used? Is there a way to avoid nested then statements? For example, if the object does not exist, I'll ensure a folder exists, then save object's icon in that folder, upload it to CDN, then remove the icon from folder, and then insert the object into DB.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to interrupt and immediate resolve promise chain with the help of `throw` operator.

```
function saidFunction((objectInfo)) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    app.models.MyObjectType.exists(objectInfo['id'])
    .then(exists => {
      if (exists) {
        throw ALREADY_EXISTS; // some constant
      }
    })
    .then(() => 
      console.log('If object does not exist, print this and do some other stuff')
    )
    .then(() => 
      resolve('Successfully completed')
    )
    .catch(error => {
      if(error === ALREADY_EXISTS) {
        resolve('Object already exists');
      } else {
        reject(error);
      }
    });
  });
}
```